# Why is ground_truth_key in AzureML text generation component required

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ml-pipelines, azure-ml-component

I'm not following why the [ground_truth_key](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-assets/blob/main/assets/training/finetune_acft_hf_nlp/components/pipeline_components/text_generation/README.md) in AzureML's text generation pipeline component is a required argument. I understand it makes sense in summarization, translation, question_answering scenarios, but for text generation, which is what I'm using it for, just the input field should suffice.

[image]

What am I missing?